# How to get IIS option value of "Require SSL"?

Tags: powershell, iis

I have a script that checks some IIS settings and parameter values, and one of the values I am trying to get is "Require SSL" for the default web site.

All I found was many references for setting this option, but not for getting its value.

I will probably need to get other parameters, but this is where I am currently stuck:

[image: The option in IIS]

For sure there is something very trivial that I am missing.

Any idea?

Comment: What version of IIS? Can you post an example of one of your existing scripts and a reference to where you go it ?

Comment: Look for the `Get-WebConfiguration` cmdlet. I found an example for the `sslFlags` property [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timomta/2013/06/22/iis-ssl-how-to-powershell-script-client-cert-required/)

Comment: @Theo, thank you for the direction. Get-WebConfiguration provides an inconsistent output format, but I did manage to get a rule: if the value in 'Value' is zero, then there is no SSL setting at all. Nick.Mcdermaid, I will post the code as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Theo, I found out the solution.

In short, the result of the following should be zero:

```
(Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site/CertEnroll’ -filter "system.webServer/security/access" -name "sslFlags").Value
```

If there is **any** SSL setting enabled in 'Require SSL', then the above will be null.

My implementation is in the lines of:

```
$SSLRequired = (Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site/CertEnroll' -filter 'system.webServer/security/access' -name 'sslFlags').Value
    if ($SSLRequired -ne 0) {
        WriteWarningToLog
    }
    else {
        WriteSuccessToLog
    }
```